# creating mysql table from dymanic list python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I have a list of strings that change dynamically. I need to create a MySQL table where each string in the list is a name of a column.Note: I have found some examples using sqlalchemy but it didn't help me at all.

here is my try:

```
f = open(filepath,"r")
pluginoutput= f.read()
pluginoptojson = json.loads(pluginoutput)
columnsnames = (pluginoptojson["columns"])
countcolumns = len(pluginoptojson["columns"])
count = 0
lst = []
for name in columnsnames:
    if count < countcolumns:
        lst.append(str(name))
        count +=1

lst.append("caseid")
createsqltable = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s""" + for t in columnsnames: """ """  (test)
c.execute(createsqltable)
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

my head is about to explode of thinking. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post an example of your input file? Thanks.

Comment: {"lines": [[2, 12121, 33, 44, "ff"], [2, 786, 33, 66, "ww"]], "columns": ["id", "testnumber", "size", "gnumber", "filenname"]}


please note: the columns values are changing from file to antoher and I might have more than 120 files :)

Comment: What about the column types? That's not in the json? You have to infer it from the lines I guess? In your example is only numbers and strings, but it is the same for your 120 files?

Comment: varchar for all of them as I will change all of them to string. the columns name will be changed in count as well as names but eventually they will be varchar.

Comment: And what about the table name? Anyway a hint: from your `columnnames`, instead of your loop, I would do something like `" VARCHAR(50),".join(columnsnames)`. From that, you have to prepend the table name and append a last "VARCHAR(50)" (or whatever the size you want to use as default. You add it to your `createsqltable` statement, and it should be ok.

Comment: I wil make the table name more dynamiic later on but at this time i will call it test1, test2 ..etc and so on. are you saying I should do it like this:
createsqltable = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s"""" VARCHAR(50),".join(columnsnames)  (test)

Comment: `createsqltable = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS """ + table_name + " (" + " VARCHAR(50),".join(columnsnames) + " VARCHAR(50))"`. Still, you will missing your primary key. I cannot test it now with a database (I would post an answer if I could test it, this is not really the way to work in SO), but anyway I just wanted to give you the hint so that maybe you can solve it on your own. Hope it helps.

Comment: I really appreciate it  lrnzcig. you have been so helpful.

Comment: No problem! I would suggest you, when you get it fixed, you post your new code as an answer to your own question, so that maybe it helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

first thanks alot to Irnzcig.

I just tested his recommendation and it worked like charm. the code is:

```
pluginoutput= f.read()
pluginoptojson = json.loads(pluginoutput)
columnsnames = (pluginoptojson["columns"])
countcolumns = len(pluginoptojson["columns"])
count = 0
lst = []
for name in columnsnames:
    if count < countcolumns:
        lst.append(str(name))
        count +=1

lst.append("caseid")
table_name = "test1"
createsqltable = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS """ + table_name + " (" + " VARCHAR(50),".join(lst) + " VARCHAR(50))"
c.execute(createsqltable)
conn.commit()

c.close()
conn.close()
gc.collect()
```